# Why is $T_{\sigma}(\sigma H)$ the kernel of $\pi_{*\sigma} : T_\sigma G \rightarrow T_{\sigma H} G/H$?

Tags: linear-algebra, differential-geometry, lie-groups, group-actions

I'm trying to understand the proof of theorem $3.62$ page 123 from "Foundations of differentiable manifolds and Lie groups" by Frank F. Warner

> Let $\eta : G \times M \rightarrow M$ be a transitive action of a Lie group on the manifold $M$ on the left. Let $m_0 \in M$ and $H = \{g \in G : \eta(g,m_0) = m_0 \}$ be the isotropy group at $m_0$. Define a mapping
> $$ \tilde \beta : G/H \rightarrow M : gH \mapsto \eta(g,m_0).$$
> Then $\tilde \beta $ is a diffeomorphism.

In the proof the author states that the kernel of the differential map of $\pi$ at $\sigma \in G $ is the tangent space to $\sigma H$ at $g$. That is

$$ \ker \pi_{*\sigma} = T_{\sigma}(\sigma H) \subset T_\sigma G.$$

where

$$ \pi_{*\sigma} : T_\sigma G \rightarrow T_{\sigma H} G/H $$

I don't understand why this is the case. I presume that it is obvious since the author doesn't give a detailed explanation.

---

My (updated) attempt (Using Thorgott's hint.)

From previous results I know that $H$ is closed which means $\sigma H$ is closed. From this I deduce that $\sigma H$ is a Lie subgroup of $G$ which is embedded in $G$.

I can therefore identify the tangent space $T_{\sigma}{\sigma H}$ with a subspace of $T_\sigma G$ by using the differential of the inclusion map.

Let $X_\sigma \in T_\sigma \sigma H$ and $X_{i(\sigma)} = i_{*\sigma} X_{\sigma} \in T_\sigma G.$ Let $f \in C^\infty (G/H)$. Then

$$ \pi_* X_{i(\sigma)} f = X_{\sigma} (f \circ \pi \circ i).$$

But $ f \circ \pi \circ i$ is constant on $\sigma H$ since $f \circ \pi \circ i(\sigma h) = f(\sigma h H) = f (\sigma H)$. Therefore

$$\pi_* X_{i(\sigma)} = 0$$ and $T_{\sigma} \sigma H \subset \ker \pi_{*\sigma}.$

Using ThorGott's hint again I want to show that $\ker \pi_{*\sigma}$ has the same dimension as $T_\sigma \sigma H = \dim H$ to show the equality.

Since $\dim T_{gH} G/H = \dim G - \dim H$ I can conclude from the rank nullity theorem that $\dim \ker \pi_* = \dim H$ only when $\pi_*$ is surjective.

How could I show surjectivity ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint:** The map $\pi$ is constant on $\sigma H$, which gives one inclusion. Equality then follows by counting dimensions.

Comment: Using the first part of your hint I've managed to show that $T_\sigma \sigma H \subset \ker \pi_{*\sigma}$ since $\pi_* \circ i_* X  (f) = X(f \circ \pi \circ i)  $ and $f\circ \pi \circ i : \sigma H \rightarrow R : \sigma h \mapsto f(\sigma h H) = f(\sigma H) $ is constant. 

For dimensions I think $T_\sigma \sigma H$ has the same dimension  $k = \dim H$ which would imply that $\ker \pi_{*\sigma }$ contains a $k$ dimensionnal subspace.  To show equality I would then have to prove that $\ker \pi_*$ is $k$ dimensional as well, but I don't know why. Any more hints  ? Thanks for your help :)

Comment: Indeed, that follows since $\pi$ is a submersion.

Comment: Thanks a lot ! I just realised that the fact that $\pi$ was a submersion was already proven in my lecture notes.